# GCM provides different registratinId in iOS and Android

Tags: cordova, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap with the phonegap-plugin-push plugin and when I try to register with an Android device I get the following registrationId:

c1p9kF2DLDc:APA91bEPdXIW-_5myCTr_QrHcCD2UGrLOMe82jB84LMmaqXhkTrMRoTdvi-u2NXG9_Qe9mv5SwpSzvtdIe33bPh8m7Kcv_x6PHMihF-syBxs-KSTVhCU7EWysl8a-F61hAJ_zqVBGQTr

and when I try the same with iOS device I get the following registrationId

8bf6bfde4482880e3ac51cb790215124b26192d57bfeb7772a3f4c6edc58711d

When I try to send a notification with the key I got from my android device, everything works great, but when I try to send a notification to my iOS device I get a response of INVALID_REGISTRATION from GCM.

I have done everything in that was wrote in the GCM website, got a development certificate from apple developer and registered it in GCM and everything went well.

Does anyone has an idea?

Comment: The iOS string that you have here is not a registration ID, it is some large hex number. The format should be similar (but not the same) to what you get on the Android device. Are you sure you're printing the right thing, or getting a registration correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is what I get as registrationId when in the on.register event of the phonegap-plugin-push

Comment: How do you get the gcm registration token? As @morepork commented the above thing you get is not a registration id. It should be very similar to what you get for Android.

Comment: This is how I get the registrationId via JS:
push.on('registration', function (data) {
            //data.registrationId
        });

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like behavior when using an older phonegap-plugin-push to version such as 1.4.2. Try upgrading to phonegap-plugin-push 1.5.2 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include senderID in ios as well

```
var push = Push.init({
  android: {
      senderID: '998370016613',
      sound: true,
      vibrate: true,
      clearNotifications: true
  },
  ios: {
      senderID: '998370016613',
      alert: 'true',
      sound: 'true'
  },
  windows: {}
});
```